# How to render Nunjucks code blocks properly?

Tags: html, gulp, markdown, nunjucks

I have a Gulp Nunjucks projekt combined with MarkDown, and I'd like to output code blocks including Nunjucks variables.

**My code is:**

```
{% raw %}
  {{ variable }}
{% endraw %}
```

**I would like to output:**

```
{{ variable }}
```

without rendering the variable, but unfortunately this is not working and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? How exactly are you processing this? `{% raw %} ... {% endraw %}` should work.

Comment: Not working means the output is empty. I just realized that the issue is coming from this in my **gulpfile.js**: `.pipe(njk({ path: paths.templates }))` where `njk` is **gulp-nunjucks-render** plugin.

Comment: Not enough information on your setup, specifically with combining markdown with nunjucks.